# ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact ... to/from central

Tags: spring, maven

I'm following this tutorial: [Spring - DAO and Service layer](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/spring-dao-and-service-layer.html)

I'm getting this error in Eclipse on my pom.xml:

```
ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.antlr:antlr:jar:3.2 
from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No response received 
after 60000
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a simple networking issue. I would recommend you attempt to access that URL  in your web browser to confirm you have connectivity: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2. You should see:

> Browsing for this directory has been disabled.
>
> [View](http://search.maven.org/#browse) this directory's contents on http://search.maven.org instead.

You may also wish to check that your local system does not require a proxy to access the Internet. If so, you need to follow [these instructions](http://www.mkyong.com/web-development/how-to-configure-proxy-settings-in-eclipse/) to configure Eclipse to use your proxy.

Comment: I am seeing the same response you are. I also have my proxy settings correctly configured in my settings.xml file.

Comment: Does antlr 3.2 even exist? Maven is downloading 2.7.7

Comment: You may wish to try 3.4. Look at the search function on the Apache repository, 3.2 is not there: http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22org.antlr%22